# Cannot get my Brother printer to work after reinstalling Ubuntu Studio

Tags: printing, brother

I've been running Ubuntu Studio for a while and my printer was working when I followed instructions from Brother (HL-L2320D) before formatting.

Short story, formatted my computer after trying to install Windows 10 on a separate HDD; my printer is working under Windows 10 but I cannot get it back to working under Ubuntu Studio. I've tried many times, and the installation looks to be going fine, but I get no joy when I try to print. When I check the printer it says:

> inactive sending data to printer

Any idea? thank you.

Comment: The problem turned out to be caused by hardware according to OP's own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved my self-induced problem; I replaced the toner and the printer works now. I had the toner light on and for some reason the machine was working ok under Windows but not Ubuntu. Go figure!!

Comment: You may enjoy [the 4th one from the bottom](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/error-haiku.html)

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour Stephane; if you go here http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2320d_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625 and click to download and SAVE what will be **linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1.gz**

then open a terminal; copy each line below; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste

```
cd Downloads

gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1.gz

sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1 HL-2320D
```

that last command unleashes the install script; watch the terminal as it runs; it may ask you questions; if it says "Do you want to specify Device URI?" for a usb connection, say NO